# List string int converting in scala

Tags: scala, list

I am confused about list of chars and int with scala. Here is my example :

```
scala> var s = "123456"
s: String = 123456

scala> s.map(_.toInt)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54)

scala> s.map(_.toInt).sum
res1: Int = 309
```

The chars are converted in ASCII code I assume, how to just transform a char in its value ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s.map(_.asDigit).sum` is the correct Scala API method. The `toInt` will return the ASCI code of the symbol, instead of the numerical representation.

```
scala> "123456".map(_.asDigit).sum
res0: Int = 21
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Character.getNumericValue(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) like

```
s.map(Character.getNumericValue(_))
```

Outputs

```
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Another option, would be subtracting `'0'` like

```
s.map(_ - '0')
```

for the same result.